# firebase signInWithCustomToken broken

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

At first, just yesterday everything worked. But from this morning, I got the case.
On back-end (NodeJS) I generate custom token with `auth().createCustomToken(SOME_ID)`

Then, when I call on client side `signInWithCustomToken()` with token I got from back-end, I get the next error:

```
{
  code: "auth/invalid-custom-token",
  message: "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."
}
```

In logs there's a POST to https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=MY_API_KEY, with params { returnSecureToken: true, token: MY_GENERATED_TOKEN } with status 400 and response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
 }
}
```

So, did google introduced some breaking changes or what?

Comment: Are you using the same project on the client as the one used to generate the custom token on your backend?

Comment: @bojeil Yeah, of course.

Comment: Do you resolved the problem? @IlyaBoyko

Answer (score 0):

**

### Manage User Sessions

**
Firebase Authentication sessions are long lived. Every time a user signs in, the user credentials are sent to the Firebase Authentication backend and exchanged for a Firebase ID token (a JWT) and refresh token. Firebase ID tokens are short lived and **last for an hour**; the refresh token can be used to retrieve new ID tokens. Refresh tokens expire only when one of the following occurs:

- The user is deleted
- The user is disabled

A major account change is detected for the user. This includes events like password or email address updates.
The Firebase Admin SDK provides the ability to revoke refresh tokens for a specified user. In addition, an API to check for ID token revocation is also made available. With these capabilities, you have more control over user sessions. The SDK provides the ability to add restrictions to prevent sessions from being used in suspicious circumstances, as well as a mechanism for recovery from potential token theft.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions
On the client side such as Angular. If you use the AngularFire2 you can use a command called signInWithCustomToken(clientToken) and pass the customToken. This will provide you with an acceptance to sign in or a rejection.

If firebase rejects, then take the rejection and either redirect the user to a login page using routes or just provide a way to login. Your call.

Just remember to let Firebase handle the decoding of the JWT. Provides better security if you do not show decoding on your side.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. The reason was that the token was expired. 
The Firebase SDK throws the same error: auth/invalid-custom-token error for both malformatted tokens and expired tokens.

Hopefully, the error handling improves soon, in the meantime developer can check to see if a token is expired by using a client side library like jtw decode and checking the "exp" timestamp and comparing to the current time.

```
timeSeconds=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis());
expSeconds = timeSeconds + 60L * 60L;
```

and set claims to this values

```
.claim("iat", timeSeconds)
.claim("exp", expSeconds)
```

the result from verification:

```
 "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyCustomTokenResponse",
    "idToken": "",
    "expiresIn": "3600",
    "isNewUser": true
```

[stackoverflow.com/questions/45110441/firebase-auth-invalid-custom-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110441/firebase-auth-invalid-custom-token)