# firebase auth/invalid-custom-token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to generate custom tokens with the firebase admin sdk

```
const uid = '91f0bf4c-3e3c-441c-a21d-6a7fee341db5'
firebaseAdmin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
```

With this specific uid sometimes the custom tokens work, other times when using authWithCustomToken() on the client side I get this error:

> “auth/invalid-custom-token”
>   The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."

Is there any way I can debug what is going on with the token? On the surface both the "good" tokens and the "bad" tokens look the same:

They have 3 parts, separated by a `.`

- The first part is 36 characters long and in both the working case and the broken case it is the exact same
- In both examples, the second part is 392 characters and they are almost the exact same
- The both examples, the third part is 342 characters long and they are different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The token is expired. The Firebase SDK throws the same error: `auth/invalid-custom-token` error for both malformatted tokens and expired tokens.

Hopefully, the error handling improves soon, in the meantime developer can check to see if a token is expired by using a client side library like [jwt decode](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) and checking the "exp" timestamp and comparing to the current time.

Answer (score 15):

Can you go to https://jwt.io and decode your custom token. It should look like this:

```
{
  "uid": "some-uid",
  "iat": 1500147255,
  "exp": 1500150855,
  "aud": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
  "iss": "firebaseserviceaccount@YOUR_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub": "firebaseserviceaccount@YOUR_PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

`YOUR_PROJECT_ID` should match the same project on your client side project.

Comment: thank you! decoding it here works and the both tokens have the same data, except for different iat and exp values

Comment: dozens of times per day, it's not "rare" but it's not common either

Comment: Does a retrial work? When you get that error try one or two more times to confirm this is not some flakiness on the Firebase Auth backend. Also you could try directly using the REST API to confirm this is not client side related: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-verify-custom-token

Comment: retrial in which way?

1) if a token is getting this error, all retries with that token always fail
2) if we generate a new token for the same UID, sometimes the new token works, sometimes it doesn't

Comment: I'll try using the REST API directly but it's a little tough to know if that is a fix because this happens in a seemingly random fashion, I haven't been able to come up with steps that repo every try

Comment: I mean retry signInWithCustomToken(customToken) with the same token. But if that doesn't help, then that means this is not some flakiness on the Auth backend side of things. If you catch an invalid custom token, you should provide it to the Firebase Support channels, even if it gets expired. They can inspect it and provide some reason why this happened.

Comment: Thanks, @bojeil, I supplied an example through firebase support channels but have not gotten a resolution yet. I can spend time digging up more example invalid tokens if that will help debug it on firebase's end

Comment: It is likely your custom token is expired and you are re-using it. The custom token has a limited lifetime. It is not indefinite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150236/discussion-between-dylanjha-and-bojeil).