# Code=17000 "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I followed the steps described here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

I am able to create custom tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK.

I send them back to the client iOS app to use like this :

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: customToken ?? "") { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

But I get this error :

```
Code=17000 "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation., error_name=ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN}
```

I'm using Firebase Admin 5.2.0 and the Firebase iOS client 4.0.0

Any idea?

Comment: Check this post for how to debug this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110441/firebase-auth-invalid-custom-token/45122102 Keep in mind the custom token lifetime is limited and it could expire if you are storing and reusing it.

Comment: I already managed to request newer one if it's expired, but my issue is that the token never works

Comment: Ok, wanted to get that out of the way. Check the decoded format of the custom token as described in that link.

Comment: @bojeil The token is correctly decoded with the correct data using the debugger jwt.io

Comment: Make sure the client side project matches the service account that generated that custom token. Try sending the token with the REST API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-verify-custom-token If that doesn't help, you should contact Firebase Support.

Comment: Thanks for your help @bojeil. One last question: where can I find the API_KEY they are mentionning in the doc?

Comment: It's in the plist.

Comment: Thanks! I tested and it returns 401. I contacted the firebase support. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

After checking the token and its lifetime, it turned out that a mismatch in system-time was the problem in our case.

After setting the timezone and the time to 'automatic', the problem was solved.

Comment: Could you please tell me where did you set this option to 'automatic'? I'm facing the same problem, my server is generating tokens 4 minutes ahead.

Comment: Automatic is about using the network time - sync with NTP.

Answer (score 0):

I try a lot time to solve it.. and I found something interesting.
The custom_toke end with "%3D%3D", this is not a valid, you need to replace is with "==".. and it will work good.